# Laravel - FatalErrorException in usahaController.php line 33: Call to a member function paginate() on a non-object

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am making a search page in Laravel and cant understand how to use the paginate method for this usage.

I have used it else where, but not like this.
usahaController

```
public function feindex() {
  $hasil= DB::select('sELECT anggota.USERNAME, kategori_usaha.NAMA_KATEGORI_USAHA, usaha.NAMA_USAHA, 
        usaha.TYPE_UMKM, usaha.GAMBAR_UMUM, usaha.ALAMAT_USAHA, usaha.NOMOR_TLPN_USAHA FROM usaha 
        JOIN anggota on usaha.ID_ANGGOTA=anggota.ID_ANGGOTA 
        JOIN kategori_usaha on usaha.ID_KATEGORI_USAHA=kategori_usaha.ID_KATEGORI_USAHA')->paginate(2);
  $keranjang['usaha']=$hasil;  
  return view('feindex', $keranjang);
}
```

view

```
@foreach ($usaha as $item)
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
  <div class="thumbnail text-center">
    <a href="single_product.html">
      <img src="{{ asset('uploads/'.$item->GAMBAR_UMUM)  }}" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
    <br/>
    <h5 class="text-primary">{{$item->NAMA_USAHA}}</h5>
    <ul>
      <li><i class="livicon" data-name="check" data-size="18" 
        data-loop="true" data-c="#787878" data-hc="787878"></i> Nama Pengusaha :<br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp{{$item->USERNAME}}</li>
      <li><i class="livicon" data-name="check" data-size="18" 
                    data-loop="true" data-c="#787878" data-hc="787878"></i> {{$item->NAMA_KATEGORI_USAHA}}</li>
      <li><i class="livicon" data-name="check" data-size="18" 
                    data-loop="true" data-c="#787878" data-hc="787878"></i> {{$item->ALAMAT_USAHA}} </li>
      <li><i class="livicon" data-name="check" data-size="18" 
                    data-loop="true" data-c="#787878" data-hc="787878"></i> {{$item->NOMOR_TLPN_USAHA}}</li>
      <li><i class="livicon" data-name="check" data-size="18" 
                    data-loop="true" data-c="#787878" data-hc="787878"></i> {{$item->TYPE_UMKM}} </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="single_product.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-white">View</a>
  </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
{!! $usaha->render() !!}
```

how fix this

Answer (score 0):

```
public function feindex() {
  $hasil= DB::select('SELECT anggota.USERNAME, kategori_usaha.NAMA_KATEGORI_USAHA, usaha.NAMA_USAHA, 
        usaha.TYPE_UMKM, usaha.GAMBAR_UMUM, usaha.ALAMAT_USAHA, usaha.NOMOR_TLPN_USAHA FROM usaha')
->join('anggota', 'usaha.ID_ANGGOTA','=','anggota.ID_ANGGOTA')
->join('kategori_usaha','usaha.ID_KATEGORI_USAHA','=','kategori_usaha.ID_KATEGORI_USAHA')
->paginate(2);

  $keranjang=$hasil;  
  return view('usaha', $keranjang);
}
```